# direct child css selector in polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

Inside a class derived from polymerElement, I have this code

```
class SelectorTest extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style>
        :host > * {
          display: block;
          margin-top: 5px;
        }
      </style>
   `
  }
```

Looks like the "greater than" symbol in **:host > "** clashes with the  **"< style >"**, and the final result is that the css is visible in the rendered page

**screenshot of the rendered page**

[image: renderer page]

If I remove the critical CSS selector, everything works fine.

So I assume that I need to somehow escape the ">".

The question is : how do I escape it ?

Comment: What do you want exactly? try to explain with an example plz?

Comment: @HakanC I want to be able to use the style posted in a Polymer element. As it is now, it breaks the displayed page

Comment: what is the difference when you use without ` > *` and your wished result. Sorry as it's not my native language and could not catch the point what is exactly you want to manipulate with style.

Comment: The problem is that the style data is visible , as text, in the rendered page

Comment: so without `* > ` doesn't fit your need ?

Comment: @HakanC The problem is that the style is rendered in the page as text, not as a style.  But it is not only the > seelctor, there must be some other problem. Thanks for your interest !

Comment: When you removed this pointer than it is working as it must too. I mean for host style just uses as it is (without this indicator). It's nature Polymer elements host styling. Then if you want to style any child, just specify explicitly the item to style it.

Comment: @vals I think this might be a bug. The problem seems to be the combination of `*` and `display:block`. If you remove `display:block`, the issue goes away. [demo](https://noiseless-glider.glitch.me)

Comment: @tony19 Thank you very much !   I had made other changes , and now I was unable to reproduce the issue. I was even thinking about closing the question as non reproducible.